# Как поднять туннель ssh через Paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko, ssh-tunnel

У меня возникла проблема при создании ssh туннеля через Paramiko. А именно, мне необходимо создать туннель следующего вида "ssh -L127.0.0.1:12222:host_2:22 user@host_1".

Пробовал решить задачу следующим образом:

```
def test_tunnel():
   mykey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('C:/Users/Alexandr/.ssh/id_rsa')
   with SSHTunnelForwarder(
           ('host_1', 22),
           ssh_username='ssh_user1',
           ssh_pkey=mykey,
           remote_bind_address=("host_2", 12222),
           local_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 12222)
   ) as tunnel:
      ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
      ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
      ssh.connect(hostname='127.0.0.1', port=12222, username='ssh_user2')
      (stdin, stdout, stderr) = ssh.exec_command("hostname")
      result = stdout.read() + stderr.read()
      ssh.close()
```

Однако при выполнении этого кода, он падает с ошибкой:

```
FAILED                                             [100%]2020-04-27 10:04:13,250| ERROR   | Secsh channel 0 open FAILED: No route to host: Connect failed
2020-04-27 10:04:13,251| ERROR   | Could not establish connection from ('127.0.0.1', 12222) to remote side of the tunnel
2020-04-27 10:04:13,251| ERROR   | Exception: Error reading SSH protocol banner
2020-04-27 10:04:13,253| ERROR   | Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-04-27 10:04:13,253| ERROR   |   File "D:\Project\my_pr\venv\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2211, in _check_banner
2020-04-27 10:04:13,254| ERROR   |     buf = self.packetizer.readline(timeout)
2020-04-27 10:04:13,254| ERROR   |   File "D:\Project\my_pr\venv\lib\site-packages\paramiko\packet.py", line 380, in readline
2020-04-27 10:04:13,254| ERROR   |     buf += self._read_timeout(timeout)
2020-04-27 10:04:13,255| ERROR   |   File "D:\Project\my_pr\venv\lib\site-packages\paramiko\packet.py", line 609, in _read_timeout
2020-04-27 10:04:13,255| ERROR   |     raise EOFError()
2020-04-27 10:04:13,255| ERROR   | EOFError
2020-04-27 10:04:13,255| ERROR   | 
2020-04-27 10:04:13,255| ERROR   | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2020-04-27 10:04:13,256| ERROR   | 
2020-04-27 10:04:13,256| ERROR   | Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-04-27 10:04:13,256| ERROR   |   File "D:\Project\my_pr\venv\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2039, in run
2020-04-27 10:04:13,256| ERROR   |     self._check_banner()
2020-04-27 10:04:13,256| ERROR   |   File "D:\Project\my_pr\venv\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2216, in _check_banner
2020-04-27 10:04:13,257| ERROR   |     "Error reading SSH protocol banner" + str(e)
2020-04-27 10:04:13,257| ERROR   | paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner
2020-04-27 10:04:13,257| ERROR   |
```

Ошибка возникает на строке `ssh.connect(hostname='127.0.0.1', port=12222, username='ssh_user2')`.

**В чем моя ошибка?**

P.S. При поднятии туннеля (ssh -L127.0.0.1:12222:host_2:22 user@host_1) руками и выполнении  кода:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
      ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
      ssh.connect(hostname='127.0.0.1', port=12222, username='ssh_user2')
      (stdin, stdout, stderr) = ssh.exec_command("hostname")
      result = stdout.read() + stderr.read()
      ssh.close()
```

он отрабатывает как нужно, т.е. проблема возникает на этапе создания туннеля.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner`

Это происходит, если сервер принимает соединение, но демон ssh не отвечает в течение 15 секунд. Это может быть перегрузка сети, неисправные коммутаторы и т. Д., Но обычно это означает, что целевой сервер отключен или его sshd завис. Восстановление это подождать и попробовать еще раз. Если вы контролируете сервер, самое время проверить его работоспособность

можно указать тайм-аут для `banner`:

```
client = SSHClient()
client.connect('ssh.example.com', banner_timeout=200)
```

так же вы можете попробовать этот пример [отсюда](https://pypi.org/project/sshtunnel)

```
import paramiko
import sshtunnel

with sshtunnel.open_tunnel(
    (REMOTE_SERVER_IP, 443),
    ssh_username="",
    ssh_pkey="/var/ssh/rsa_key",
    ssh_private_key_password="secret",
    remote_bind_address=(PRIVATE_SERVER_IP, 22),
    local_bind_address=('0.0.0.0', 10022)
) as tunnel:
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect('127.0.0.1', 10022)
    # do some operations with client session
    client.close()

print('FINISH!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел ошибку в собственном коде. В строке `remote_bind_address=("host_2", 12222)` был указан не верный порт. Для данного случая необходимо было указать порт 22.